Function to clear allocated memory is not working
I'm trying to make a DTC in C. This is the structure of the nodes:
typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *lower;
    struct node *higher;
} node;

To free the memory allocated using malloc(), I've implemented this function:
void free_nodes(node*a) {
    if(a->higher != NULL) {
        free_nodes(a->higher);
    }
    if(a->lower != NULL) {
        free_nodes(a->lower);
    }
    if(a->higher == NULL && a->lower == NULL) {
        free(a);
    }
}

It takes the pointer to the root node as a parameter.
I tried to use recursion here but it does not seem to free all the nodes. It is only able to free two nodes (I checked using valgrind).

I forgot to mention that the *higher and *lower values of the end nodes are set to NULL and do not have garbage values.


I tried to use recursion here but it does not seem to free all the nodes.

The current node (a) is freed only if its a->higherand a->lower are NULL. Since they are not set to NULL anywhere, a will not be freed.
Instead a should always be freed as long as it is itself not NULL.
void free_nodes(node*a) {
    if (a == NULL) {
        return; // nothing to do
    }
    free_nodes(a->higher); // no need to check for `NULL` here, it will be done in the recursive call
    free_nodes(a->lower);  // no need to check for `NULL` here, it will be done in the recursive call
    free(a);  // we know that a is not NULL since it was checked in the beggining
}

Note that none of the pointers are actually set to NULL after freeing them. For the sub nodes it does not really matter. But the root node should be set to NULL by the caller after calling free_nodes with it.
Alternatively you can change free_nodes to accept a node**a (pointer to pointer) and set it to NULL inside it. This will require using *a all over, which is a bit more cumbersome, but from a design point of view it has the advantage that it guarantees a pointer will not remain non-NULL after it was freed, so there's no risk of double-free.
A final note:
The body of free_nodes can also be written equivalently as:
if (a) {     // the same as `if (a != NULL)`
    free_nodes(a->higher); // no need to check for `NULL` here, it will be done in the recursive call
    free_nodes(a->lower);  // no need to check for `NULL` here, it will be done in the recursive call
    free(a);  // we know that a is not NULL since it was checked in the beggining
}

Which style is better is a matter of personal preference (I personally prefer the first version, when the edge case is handled first and the rest is unconditional).

Oh man this is way simpler. Thanks for the answer.

Even simpler with a single exit point: if (a != NULL) { ... }.

@AugustKarlstrom I considered it. I guess it is a matter of personal preference but evetualy I thought the logic is cleaner when the edge case is handled first and the rest is unconditional.

@wohlstad Yes, pure structured programming is not for everyone :-)

@AugustKarlstrom added a note with the alternative style.

And if so?
void free_nodes(node*a){

    if(a-> higher != NULL){
        free_nodes(a-> higher);
        a-> higher = NULL;    // This isn't necessary if you remove the last check
    }
    if(a-> lower != NULL){
        free_nodes(a-> lower);
        a-> lower = NULL;     // This isn't necessary if you remove the last check
    }
    // If you remove this check, then you don't need to set anything to NULL
    if(a-> higher == NULL && a-> lower == NULL){
        free(a);
    }
}

Thus, it can be simplified to:
void free_nodes(node*a){

    if(a-> higher != NULL){
        free_nodes(a-> higher);
    }
    if(a-> lower != NULL){
        free_nodes(a-> lower);
    }
    free(a);
}

A single check at the beginning (if (a == NULL)) is more concise, but it performs one unnecessary check for the root node.

There's little point in setting the pointers to null if you know you're going to free the node at the end. The right solution is to just get rid of the check.

Barmar, checking for NULL of these pointers caused the issue, so I left it in the code.

A useful reason to set the values to NULL is that spurious access to free'd memory is more likely to trigger an earlier UB.  No guarantees here though.

Your code doesn't check that the pointer argument is not null before using it.  That much defensive coding is probably worthwhile.  It allows you to simplify the function: if (a != NULL) { free(a->lower); free(a->higher); free(a); }.

I just wanted to focus on a common mistake when a pointer to a deleted object remains. And this mistake was made by the OP.

@JonathanLeffler, and if we treat this function as a destructor in C++? That is, why check for NULL if no one but me can reset my pointer.

What about it?  It will work.  The check for null at the top means you don't have to check for null before calling it recursively.  And I see I made a typo; the calls free(a->lower); free(a->higher); should be recursive calls — free_nodes(a->lower); free_nodes(a->higher);.  Sorry about that — it's hard to spot on a cell phone (and much easier to spot on a laptop).

@JonathanLeffler, I understood you right away, a typo is not terrible, if we talk about a simpler function, then wohlstad gave us the most detailed answer, and I voted for his answer.

@KonstantinMakarov That is, why check for NULL if no one but me can reset my pointer Because the you from six months from now won't know what the you from six months ago did.  Or maybe even six days from now. If you write enough code, eventually you'll come back to some of your old code and wonder who that utter moron was...

@AndrewHenle, If you don't trust yourself, you can go to extremes, such as in C#. Let's say we need to assign a value to an array element: 1. Checking an array for NULL. 2. Checking a parameter for Type. 3. Comparing an index with 0. 4. Comparing an index with the array size. 5. Assignment.
